# Filter on document reference as a field

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have 3 collections:

1. User => with some field
2. Organization => with some field
3. UserOrg with fields like:

   - uid // user id
   - orgid // orgid
   - userDetails // document reference of user doc like  user/uid
   - orgDetails //  document reference of org doc like  org/uid

Now I need to fetch user details of user details

My code is:

```js
return this.dbCollectionService.userOrganizationCollection.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(res => {
        return res.map(data => {
          var userData = data.payload.doc.data()
         let userDetails : any;
         if (userData.userDetails) {

this.angularFirestore.doc(userData.userDetails).valueChanges().subscribe(res => {
          userDetails = res;
          console.log(userDetails);
        });

      return { id, ...userDetails }

    }).filter( f => f.organizationId != undefined && f.organizationId == orgId)
  }));
```

This is able to console the result correctly, but not returning data.

Could be getting data from data reference taking time and return statement executes earlier.

Comment: This is one of the instances where it's probably better to denormalize data and duplicate them as needed into other collections. In this case, better to have a copy of `userDetails` and `orgDetails` inside `UserOrg` document. Checkout: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA

Answer (score 0):

The `return { id, ...userDetails }` is executed before the subscription on the `this.angularFirestore`
`.doc(userData.userDetails).valueChanges()`.

Subscription inside a subscription is not a good idea, you should use other pipable operators like switchMap to chain the two calls :

```
return this.dbCollectionService
.userOrganizationCollection.snapshotChanges()
.pipe(
   map(res => res.map(data => data.payload.doc.data())),
   map(userDatas => userDatas.filter(_ => _)),
   map(userDatas => userDatas.map(this.angularFirestore.doc(userData.userDetails).valueChanges()
                                    .pipe(map(userDetails => ({ id, ...userDetails }))))),
   switchMap(userDatas$ => combineLatest(userDatas$)),
   map(users => users.filter( f => f.organizationId != undefined && f.organizationId == orgId))
);
```

Comment: you are also doing nested subscription

Comment: woups bad copy paste, I'm fixing it.